# Append suffix to colnames

Tags: r, suffix

I have multiple columns of different names in a data frame. For all of them i would like to add a common suffix

```
tot_proc
```

So, for example

```
DF
a   b   c
```

->

```
DF
a_tot_proc   b _tot_proc   c_tot_proc
```

I was able only to figure out how to add a prefix for column names:

```
colnames(DF) <- paste("tot_proc", colnames(DF), sep = "_")
```

but not suffix.Could you please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Just revert the order in `paste`: `colnames(DF) <- paste(colnames(DF), "tot_proc", sep = "_")`

Comment: Thank you!!! hehe, it worked! :)

Answer (score 18):

You could just switch the order around.

```
colnames(DF) <- paste(colnames(DF), "tot_proc", sep = "_")
```

Comment: A handy generalized function: `appendDataFrameColumns<-function(df, prefix="", suffix="", sep="") { colnames(df) <- paste(prefix, colnames(df), suffix, sep=sep) return(df) }`

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr::rename_with`

```r
library(dplyr)
DF %>% rename_with(~ paste(., "tot_proc", sep = "_"))
```